# Sort Array By Date Attribute, Ordered By Nearest to Current Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Array of Contact objects...

```
[#<Contact id: 371, full_name: "Don Hofton", birthday: "2013-11-07">,...]
```

And I need to order them by birthdays nearest to the current time AND remove objects from the array that have birthdays greater than 4 months away.  Here is what I've got so far, but it's not working....

```
@contacts_with_birthday_data = Contact.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where("birthday IS NOT NULL")
        @current_time = Time.now
        @contacts_with_birthday_data.each do |c|
            c.birthday = c.birthday[0..4]
            c.birthday = Date.parse(c.birthday)
        end
        @contacts_with_birthday_data = @contacts_with_birthday_data.sort! { |a,b| b[:birthday] <=> a[:birthday] }
        @contacts_with_birthday_data = @contacts_with_birthday_data.sort! { |a| a.birthday < DateTime.now }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this all with one query:

```
Contact \
  .where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  .where("birthday > ?", 4.months.ago)
  .order("birthday desc")
```

If `4.months.ago` is used in a scope, make sure to wrap it in a lambda or Proc, or it will be calculated when the class is loaded and not on subsequent calls. This has bit me more than once!

Alternatively, in a non-Rails world, you could use the `reject` and `sort_by` methods on Enumerable:

```
contacts = [#your array of contacts]
contacts.reject { |c| c.birthday < 4.months.ago }.sort_by(&:birthday).reverse
```

If you haven't seen the syntax used in `sort_by`, that's actually equivalent to `sort_by { |c| c.birthday }`. That syntax tells Ruby to convert the birthday method to a Proc object, then call the Proc against each instance in your array.

Comment: Huh? I would assume that every contact has a birthday, or that only contacts with birthdays should be included. If you want to include contacts without birthdays, you could do `where("birthday is null OR birthday > ?", 4.months.ago)`.

Comment: Huh? Birthday is a date like "1990-01-17". Your query only find contacts whose date of birth is within the next 4 months. Is that more clear for you? You may want to change the year: `birtday.change(year: Date.today.year)`. That will make sense.